# Sorting by date and time from csv-File in Java using streams

Tags: java, sorting, datetime, java-stream

i am trying to sort my csv-File by date and time.Is there any possibility to do this with streams? The dateformat in the csv-file looks like this. 26.01.2020 23:14:25. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Logfilereader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");


        Stream<String> rows1 = Files.lines(Path.of("C:\\Users\\julit\\IdeaProjects\\Logfilereader\\src\\testdata1.csv"));
        rows1
                .map(x -> x.split(";"))
                .filter(x -> x.length == 5)
                .filter(x -> Integer.parseInt(x[1])>=0)
                .filter(x -> x[2].equals("HYGRO")||x[2].equals("TEMP"))
                .filter(x -> x[4].equals("CELSIUS")||x[4].equals("PERCENT"))
                .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x[0]+ " "+x[1]+" " +x[2]+ " "+x[3]+ " "+ x[4]));

        rows1.close();


        }



    }
```

Comment: You want `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: yes thats the timeformat, thats given. i want to sort the entries in the csv file by date and time :)

Comment: No, I mean, you need lower case y and capital H.  Your code sample suggests otherwise.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and also `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: A tip: fill spaces into your expressions, and they will be a lot easier to read (for many of us). So `Integer.parseInt(x[1]) >= 0`, `x[0] + " " + x[1] + " " + x[2] + " " + x[3] + " " + x[4]` and `x[2].equals("HYGRO") || x[2].equals("TEMP")`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
.sorted(
        Comparator.comparing( ( String line ) -> 
            LocalDateTime.parse(          // Parse each date-time string into a `LocalDateTime` object. This class implements `Comparable`, so we need do nothing more.
                line.split( "," )[ 1 ] ,  // Grab date-time portion of line.
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) // Define a formatting pattern to match your input text.
            ) 
        )
)
```

Also, your formatting pattern must match your input. So if the input uses dots, don’t put slashes in your formatter: `dd.MM.uuuu` rather than `dd/MM/uuuu`.

## Details

### `Stream#sorted`

Call [`Stream#sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted()) while passing a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation.

For each line, our comparator calls [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to get an array of its two parts, the name and the date-time. We extract the second element of that array with the zero-based index of `[1]`. Lastly we parse the date-time portion of the line into a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object. That class implements [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), so we need do nothing more to create our comparator.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss" );
String input =
        """
        Alice,23.01.2022 23:30:00
        Bob,12.01.2022 12:30:00
        Carol,15.01.2022 15:30:00
        Davis,01.01.2022 01:30:00
        """;

List < String > result =
        input.lines()
                .sorted(
                        Comparator.comparing( ( String line ) -> LocalDateTime.parse( line.split( "," )[ 1 ] , f ) )
                )
                .toList();
```

When run.

> result = [Davis,01/01/2022 01:30:00, Bob,12/01/2022 12:30:00, Carol,15/01/2022 15:30:00, Alice,23/01/2022 23:30:00]

### ISO 8601

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. ISO 8601 defines textual formats for exchanging date-time values. The standard is built to eliminate ambiguity, and to facilitate reading by both machines and humans.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default. This  eliminates the need to specify a formatting pattern.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, fixed. I hadn't noticed the mismatch in the Question between example data and formatting pattern.